# mysql select 1 item with status 1. Else select any item

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

**images:**

```
| ID | itemID | title  | status | publish |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|  1 |  251   | title1 |      0 |       1 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|  2 |  251   | text   |      0 |       0 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|  3 |  251   | text2  |      0 |       1 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|  4 |  252   | ttl1   |      1 |       1 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
|  5 |  252   | blabla |      0 |       1 |
```

I need to select just one item (image) from table. SQL query like:

```
SELECT 
    `ID` 
FROM 
    `images` 
WHERE 
    `images`.`itemID` = 251 
    AND
    `status` = 1 OR if no image has status = 1 then select any image
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    `ID` 
FROM 
    `images` 
WHERE 
    `images`.`itemID` = 251
ORDER BY `status` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If `status` values are not constrained to `(0, 1)` then simply substitute `ORDER BY` clause with:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `status` = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/449787/1)

Comment: Wow it's so easy. Tnx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be easier than you think. Just sort by status, assuming it can only be a 0 or 1 and the desired `itemID` is present.

```
SELECT 
    `ID` 
FROM 
    `images` 
WHERE 
    `images`.`itemID` = 251
ORDER BY
    `status` DESC
LIMIT 1
```